# Video camera capture landscape video from portrait activity

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm have the following problem, I built an portrait activity with camera's surface view which is landscape. Now, I want that the captured video would be also like the surface's orientation - landscape, and not like the activity's orientation which is portrait.

The output video is always in portrait not matter what I'm doing(I added the camera's sources to my project and I'm working with it)

So, finaly, as I see it the native camera library takes the device orientation when starting to capture the video an produces corresponding video. Does anyone know if I can bypass it, maybe "tricking" the device to think that he in landscape mode useing the Accelerometer?

Comment: AFAIK, all videos shot with `MediaRecorder` are recorded in landsacpe, regardless of physical orientation or anything else.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's great to know that. Do you mean that if i'll shot video using MediaRecorder it will produce landscape video file? Do you have maybe a good reference? +1 for you.

Comment: "Do you mean that if i'll shot video using MediaRecorder it will produce landscape video file?" -- yes. "Do you have maybe a good reference?" -- because it works that way on every device I have ever tried with my CWAC-Camera library, and the documentation provides no sign of how to have `MediaRecorder` behave otherwise. While `setOrientationHint()` claims to have an effect, I have never gotten any results from it. So, I don't have a reference, other than "the school of hard knocks". :-)

Comment: Maybe you are right but i did some tests on my camera(I used the camera source code) and if device is in portrait the MediaRecorder will always shot in portrait, if I'm changing to orientationHint it creates rotated portrait video.

Comment: Using `setOrientationHint()`? What device are you testing with?

Comment: Yep, on Samsung Galaxi S4 and LG Nexus 4.

Comment: It's not the solution but after investigation we decided here to do it in JNI. From native you can do crop on native media recorder, I don't have any code to present so I'm not marking this question as an answered one. About the preview - it's easy to stimulate landscape mode in portrait device, just create 2 black views and cover the top and bottom of the portrait preview.